# php if statement where a variable == variable value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

```
$my_zip = $user->zip; 
$zipstring = $rows['zip_code_pool'];

if ( $zipstring == $my_zip ) {      
      echo "in the area!<br />";
}
```

This of course, does not work. 
echo `$zipstring` would look like: `90000,90001,90002`   (zip_code_pool column has many values per row)
`echo $my_zip` would only be `90000`

How can I use an if statement to see if `$my_zip` exists in a rows `$zipstring`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( in_array($my_zip, explode(',', $zipstring) )) {      
  echo "in the area!<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

- `explode` will return an array with all your `zip`
- `in_array` will check whether this array contains your `zip`

> ```
> $my_zip = $user->zip; 
> $zipstring = $rows['zip_code_pool'];
>
> $zipPieces = explode(",", $zipstring);
> if (in_array($my_zip, $zipPieces)) {      
>       echo "in the area!<br />";
> }
> ```

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) and [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
$zipstring = '90000,90001,90002';
$zip_aray = explode(",",$zipstring);
$my_zip = '90000';
if(in_array($my_zip,$zip_aray)){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```